# PC VGA-out to TV HDMI-in cable possible?

Tags: hdmi, tv, vga

I bought a VGA to HDMI cable, and attempt to connect the laptop VGA out to the TV HDMI in. However I'm not able to turn on the external monitor output on the laptop, when checking it and clicking ok, it just turns back off.

So what am I missing?  Is this not supposed to work? Is there no analog input pins in the HDMI port? Or what?

What are my options?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the spec of the TV:

[image]

I have two computers I variably need to connect, they have these outputs;

1. has VGA and S-video
2. has VGA

So I guess I can get a cable VGA to S-video?  [like this?](http://cgi.ebay.com/Adaptor-VGA-D-Sub-SVideo-S-Video-RCA-TV-Cable-PC-/260477902814?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3ca5b15fde) + extension
And only connect the 4-pin s-video?

Will any other connection, like the scarts, or YPbPr (whatever it is?) give better quality image, sharper?  Or it will be the same?

Comment: this is not a direct answer to your question, but using something like [this](http://www.cooldrives.com/usb-hdmi-adapter-dvi.html) (a USB video adapter with HDMI out) may work if you can't find another solution

Comment: Thanks! It's an option. Have you tried it? Any comment on picture quality compared to VGA-to-component?  I would guess it should be sharper, as this is all digital? ,

Comment: @user i have not tired this particular device, or any USB-HDMI adapters. i have, however, had occassion to use USB-DVI adapter, and it works well enough. I would say any desktop applications will work fine, but i wouldn't expect to play 3D games on it.

Comment: I see. I just need for financial charts, so should not be resource-heavy, but what's important for me is the pixel-sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HDMI pinout description on http://pinouts.ru/Video/hdmi_pinout.shtml I don't see how this could possibly work.

There is no analogue on HDMI.  The video image would need to be captured into an image buffer then retransmitted as a digital bitstream.  While theoretically possible, it wouldn't be easy - nor cheap.

Flicking through one of my supplier's catalogues I see:

- VGA to S-Video / Composite
- S-Video / Composite to VGA
- DVI-D to VGA/RGB/Component
- DVI-D & SPDIF to HDMI
- HDMI to Composite / S-Video & Stereo Audio

There is no sign of a VGA to HDMI.

Comment: It seems so, analog/digital, so will not work. What about VGA to SCART, is that possible?

Comment: VGA to Scart at the correct frame size & refresh rate may work.  VGA to composite (as noted above) or S-Video is available, and either of those can be adapted through Scart if you want to.  You would only get standard definition TV, not HD.

Comment: I see. Added TV spec above, shows both S-video, YPbPr, RGB scart and S-video scart. Should these all give basically same quality, resolution/sharpness?

Comment: Component (YPbPr) and RGB Scart would give the sharpest image.  S-video and S-video scart are the same thing just a different plug, and will be slightly fuzzier.

Comment: ok, that makes sense..  I'll go for the VGA-to-Component then.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

VGA and Audio to HDMI cannot possibly work as a cable, however you can purchase adaptors to do this e.g. http://cpc.farnell.com/pro-signal/psg03649/vga-audio-to-hdmi-scaler/dp/AV21380?Ntt=AV21380 and many others.

The answer above suggesting USB to HDMI was a good suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from VGA to HDMI requires an active converter. There are a load of dodgy chinese sellers selling cables with a VGA plug on one, a HDMI plug on the other and no electronics but very few if any devices will work with such a cable.

Converting between VGA and HDMI requires active electronics. You can get VGA to HDMI converters in a "cable wart" form factor powered from a USB port but they are much less common than converters that are designed to convert the other way round. I've used one but it wasn't mine and I don't know who made it. A google image search for "vga to hadmi converter" finds several such devices but none look exactly like the one I used.